# How to add 2nd foreground color for same text in lwuit

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

How to add 2nd foreground color for same text in lwuit?

```
    Label lable=new Label();
    lable.setText("This is a Lable");
    lable.getStyle().setFgColor(0xffffff);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't set two colors or styles to a single label. You can place multiple labels in a `Container` that has either a `flow layout` or a `BoxLayout X_AXIS` layout to achieve that same effect.